# Search Results: People by Department AND Sub-Department

Tags: search-results, managed-metadata, term-store, people-search, term

**Can SharePoint Search People by Department and include Sub-Departments?**

- My organization has Departments with Sub-Departments.
- I have created terms in the term store:

**For example:**

1. Training Department

   - Training Sub-Department A
   - Training Sub-Department B
   - Training Sub-Department C

I created a page using the term "Training Department". On that page I added a search result webpart. The query is for people with **Department: {Term.IDWithChildren}**.

This method works for documents, but not people. Anyone know why?

Thanks!